# Локализация игр Cocos2d-x на lua

Tags: lua, cocos2d

Создаю игру на lua при помощи движка `cocos2d-x`. Необходим способ локализации (желательно, с использованием `gettext`). Нашёл, как реализован схожий функционал на C++: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/tutorial-multiple-language-support/16237, но нет упоминаний того, как это сделать на lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После небольшой адаптации можно использовать этот модуль https://github.com/kaishiqi/I18N-Gettext-Supported.git (раздел про lua).